# Two root entries in my passwd file

Tags: security, root

In Ubuntu 20.04, there are two root entries I find in my passwd file.

When I use  `grep root /etc/passwd`, I get:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

and when I use `grep root /etc/group`, I get:

```
root:x:0:
```

and when I use `grep root /etc/shadow`, I get:

```
root:$6$SdmRmWLQLDizwk9Y$T4TiAQS1cml..78.Ac00hj9HHq5oo8EzoJBJEdhUMlLA9s9fQO89BBwB35pUxRvlprl1kaMZtQYSicMLqXCur.:19300:0:99999:7:::
```

I never changed my root password, but the number 19300 means I changed it 7 days ago.

Is it normal to have two root users in my machine?

And if not, what does that mean?

Comment: It means something probably messed up when you too the unexpected action of adding a root password.  Ubuntu was set up explicitly without a root password. Probably doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: So that's mean nothing, just a little problem would happen when i set root password?

Comment: How old is your system? Do you have backups of these files? What are the contents of the respective files whose names end with a dash (`-`)?

Comment: I reinstall ubuntu 20.04 one month ago,and i think you mean that?

Comment: I haven't backups any files. The files that end with (-) are all under "/etc". Like subuid- , group-, passwd- ,etc. Beside "/var/lib/snapd/assertions/asserts-v0/snap-revision/3DKPgFxvvKtdXIQlhNSGxrT6vMpab_oZTPq2_Ei91UeRsrjO4lSN-9olDJBDG9x-"